# childBrowser.jar plugin for phonegap throws error in: settings.setPluginState(true);

Tags: javascript, cordova, jar, childbrowser

I'm trying to use the childBrowser plugin for phonegap and it's failing to generate the .apk,

In Eclipse I can see an error (deprecated function) at:

```
settings.setPluginState(true);
```

The problem here is that both versions have this line, anyway I commented this line (with not so many hopes) but it's still failing

By failing I mean that this:

```
window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage('http://google.com/')
```

Is not opening any page or throwing any errors...

Any idea what I'm missing?

PD: I included the .jar, the .js (and referenced it), the lines in androidmanifest.plist and in config.xml

-EDIT-

[image]

Phonegap: 2.1.0
childBrowser: 2.0

-EDIT-

If waiting untill device ready then I get this error in the console's simulator:

```
E/Web Console(30411): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childBrowser' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/js/scripts.js?v=33s:883
```

Comment: What version of cordova and plugin you use?

Comment: Cordova 2.1.0 and Childbrowser version is 2.0

Comment: The childbrowser functions will be available only after deviceready event. So have you tried inside that? Also have you included the .js file and .java files in their correct locations? If not nothing will work.

Comment: Also what Android version? Is that anything below 2.3?

Comment: @Purus Updated question with a screenshot of what I think my Android version is. Any ideea what version of childBrowser should I use with cordova 2.1 and android 4.3? (shall I swich to 2.2?) Thanks

Comment: Maybe I will make my life easier by updating my cordova version to the latest one? (Is it enough to replace the cordova jar and js files?)

Comment: ( sorry for the breaked comments ) Updated question with error If I wait for the deviceready event

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a particular requirement to stick with PhoneGap 2.1, use the [command-line interface](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface) and version 3+. The child browser plugin is now distributed with Cordova by default.

This is as easy as:

```
$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
$ cordova platform add android
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

Then add your HTMLs to the `www` directory and build your app using:

```
$ cordova build android
```

To open a URL in a child browser, call the following in JavaScript:

```
window.open("http://google.com/", "_blank");
```

Comment: What if my project already exists? Shall I ommmit first line? also from what path shall I run that?

Comment: It depends on how much the original project modified the default PhoneGap Java project. If it just dealt with HTMLs (the `www` directory) and didn't do anything special in Java then you might as well just drop the old project, create a new one and copy in the HTMLs. You can chalk this down as a migration from 2.x to 3.x, if there's a client or a project manager looking over your shoulder. NB: some default features in 2.x became plugins in 3.x (e.g. the `connection` object). You can run the commands above from anywhere once Cordova is properly installed (`$ sudo npm install -g cordova`).

Comment: But if I run it from anywhere, how will it know where to save it?

Comment: The `create` command creates a directory with an base Cordova (PhoneGap) project. The `platform`, `plugin` and `build` commands are run from inside that directory and are executed against that project. The `www` directory is also inside that directory. Drop your HTMLs in there.

Comment: The thing is that I created and setted up the whole project with eclipse, via GUI, so I don't have to tools I guess ( cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
-bash: cordova: command not found )

Comment: Also OMG, just realised; inAppBrowser is not childBroser ;)

Comment: "inAppBrowser" is the new name for "childBrowser" `;-)` To use the command lines tools you first need to install them (on Mac/Unix: `sudo npm install -g cordova`). A prerequisite is to have NodeJS already installed. See the docs here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_cli_index.md.html

Comment: But can I integrate facebook connect wit this?

Comment: Sure can: `cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git`

Answer (score 1):

The error you have mentioned says that you dont have valid .js file included which is needed for the plugin to work.

The recommended way to add/remove any plugin is by using the CLI.

Make sure you have included .js file in your html file below cordova.js file.

Also update to the recent version of Cordova.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot comment this line:

```
settings.setPluginState(true);
```

**Important Info:** But if you are using `Simulator`, Unfortunately, `plugins` are currently not supported in `Simulator` - you can only work with them on a real device.

Otherwise you will get the error that you said:

```
E/Web Console(30411): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childBrowser' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/js/scripts.js?v=33s:883
```

Because of course if you dont initialize the plugins you will have:

```
window.plugins = undefined
```

Because property `plugins` of the window do not exists natively, you have to create/initialize it.

You can open a child window in javascript like this:

```
window.showModalDialog("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: But then I need to replace it, if not, the app wont compile because of this line...

Comment: read this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setPluginState%28android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState%29 you're right

Comment: why do you need to use `window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage()` ? can't you use `window.showModalDialog()` it do not works ?

Comment: I didn't test it; but I just want childBrowser so I can implement the facebook connect

Comment: What kind of `Facebook` connect ? show me what you are wanting to do, maybe i have another solution to you :)